# Export / finding GraphQL Schema with Strapi and GraphQL plugin

Tags: graphql, strapi, intellij-plugin

I’m new to Strapi and to GraphQL.
I successfully created a website that uses Apollo to query data from my Strapi website.
So functionally I have everything I need.

For my DX I’m wondering:

1. Since I installed the GraphQL IntelliJ plugin: Where do I find the schemas for it? I read something about remote schema detection - is that supported with Strapi GraphQL Plugin? Where can I read about it? Otherwise how can I export GraphQL schema files from Strapi?
2. If I got 1) to work: Will TypeScript types work out of the box? Would I use one of the GraphQL schema to TS converters out there? It feels like there might be something working automatically, but I can’t tell till I get 1) to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you asked two separate questions and should therefore separate then in two separate threads.

To answer your first question: Here is how you can utilise the GraphQL IntelliJ plugin:

1. You need to create a `.graphlconfig` file. In Webstorm select your project folder and go to 'File' -> 'New' -> 'GraphQl Configuration File'.
   [image: Create new Graphql Configuration File]
2. Change the endpoint url to your strapi endpoint.
   [image: Adjust endpoint url]
3. Visit the GraphQl Tool Window, double click your endpoint and select 'Get GraphQl Schema from Endpoint (introspection)'. This will retrieve the schema file from strapi and save it to `schema.graphql`.
   [image: Get GraphQl Schema from Endpoint (introspection)]
4. Now you can run queries against your endpoint, e.g. create a new Scratch File `scratch.graphql` and run queries against your endpoint or try to figure out how to solve your second question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer! This was helpful!

Further to this, one query - typically, is .graphlconfig committed to git repo and scratch.graphql ignored from the git repo?

In addition for others looking for a similar solution - you could use values from *.env.* using the format below:

```json
    {
      "name": "Strapi GraphQL Schema",
      "schemaPath": "schema.graphql",
      "extensions": {
        "endpoints": {
          "Default GraphQL Endpoint": {
            "url": "${env:GRAPHQL_HOST}/graphql",
            "headers": {
              "Authorization": "Bearer ${env:GRAPHQL_TOKEN}",
              "user-agent": "JS GraphQL"
            },
            "introspect": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
```